# Should I use Array.map in a JS Library even with its poor performance?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to think the best solution for a [NodeJS library](https://github.com/notaphplover/ant-js) I've been writting in the last year. In this project, performance definitively matters. The current performance is good (we've been able to reduce our response times in a 30%) but I'm trying to find ways to make a better library.

After some research, I realized that I use Array.map in some critical functions. Since Array.map has to check for possible empty values, it has to be slower than any function that does the same without performing that check. I wanted to know how slow is Array.map, so I wrote a [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/u4k52g55dn) and run it with the latest version of Google Chrome.

I expected Array.map to be slow, but not as much! Array.map seems to be 90% slower than other equivalent codes. So now I have a problem.

I'd love to get that extra performance for free and I would probably reduce the response time in 1ms, but in the other hand the real bottleneck is in some data provider's response times and I'm depending on benchmarks that could change in new V8 releases.

What should I do? I know I'm taking too much time in a micro optimization, but I feel I can learn an important lesson that could be extrapolated to many similar problems.

Comment: While Array.map may be slower than an alternative, have you determined that it is a non-negligible contributor to your load times?

Comment: The important lesson would be to [avoid microbenchmarks](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) like the one you've written. How often does your actual code construct arrays with `new Array(len)`? Instead, always do benchmarks with real data, for best results do the benchmarks in your real system. I doubt avoid `map` will affect the response time at all.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using your own `map` fn if you know you don't need to worry about sparse arrays, although I'd curry it. It would be nice if you could tell the engine not to worry about sparse arrays when using `Array.prototype.map` and friends, though.

Comment: You're doing basically what [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/map.js) does, probably for the same reasons. So you're in good company. One option would be to use lodash: with as many users/contributors as they have, pretty good chance they'll catch it if/when native map improves and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @tex you can definitely tell it not to worry about sparse arrays: never pass it a sparse array.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If that's all it takes, I'm in good shape. I'm confident I haven't passed a single sparse array to `map` in production code in the past decade (`underscore.map` & `Array.prototype.map`).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm under the impression that a `hasOwnProperty` check is done on every index, regardless of whether one has ever passed a sparse array to `Array.prototype.map`. Are you saying some engines will decide to skip this step if your arrays are always well-behaved?

Comment: @tex engines are allowed to optimize as long as the observable outcome is the same

Comment: @Matthew It's hard to determine that, but after reading some comments I think I need to work harder on this. As Bergi pointed (I loved that post ^_^) maybe it was not a good idea to extract conclusions based on micro benchmarks, so I will profile some real life cases and compare the differences.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I really enjoyed that post. I'll profile some real life cases and hope the sphinx does not eat me.

Comment: Interesting I don't see such an improvement method1 vs method2 on here: http://jsben.ch/6Gk2g   (not 8 times, but just about 33% difference)

Comment: @David784 That's really interesting, I did not know lodash implemented a custom map function. Seems to be perfect for my case, I will keep an eye on it

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez You may want to read this article, as well, to get a better understanding of various v8 optimizations of array operations: https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds

Comment: @tex Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bergi if I converted his tests to just method1 and method2, and run it on my Macbook's Node.js for 1,000,000 times, method 1 took 3.1 seconds, and method 2 took 1.8 seconds.  If I then run it on Google Chrome v79, it is similar time for method 1 and 2.5 seconds for method2, so Array.map is slower but not that much, not like 8 or 10 times. There should be something wrong with the benchmark website's way of testing them. It seemed method2 had some kind of speed up / optimization / caching that made it 8 or 10 times faster

Answer (score 0):

If performance *definitively matters* it's not unreasonable try out easy potential optimizations like these. In the first place `Array.map` is an extra function call that invokes many extra function calls to do something that can already be done very succinctly with a simple iterator, so it's pretty common for it to perform slower than native for-loops - but as pointed out in comments below, v8 performs many optimizations and the only way you'll get a good answer on whether it'll make your code appreciably faster is to profile it yourself.

If it's in some critical functions, it's perfectly reasonable to try swapping your `.map()`s with for-loops and run some benchmarks to see if it makes enough difference to warrant the potential losses in readability and maintainability.

Comment: Actually yes, [v8 does perfectly optimise most iteration methods](https://youtu.be/m9cTaYI95Zc?t=951)

Comment: "*`Array.map` is an extra function call that invokes many extra function calls*" it's going to be a function call into native code that may as well be faster despite being more generic. So, "it's an extra function call" is not a good argument.

Comment: In addition, with speculative optimization, if the `array.map()` is found to always be called on a native array, with the native array method, the function call overhead itself could very well be optimized out as well.

Comment: @VLAZ That still involves creating new function scopes each and every invocation, but yes, it may be faster. I've personally yet to see a benchmark where `.map()` beat out a for-loop, but it's true that the only good answer to questions like these is to profile it yourself in your own code and see if it makes a difference. I'll edit the answer in kind.

Comment: @Klaycon it's not a matter of "beating". It's a matter of whether a major refactor to less readable and maintainable code is really worth an optimization that has yet to even be tangibly measured.